# Use different return type in member function based on template argument size

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, endianness

I'm currently dealing with SCSI parameter data blocks. SCSI numbers are big-endian, in contrast to my Windows PC. Those numbers can be 2, 3, 4, 6 or 8 bytes long, and are stored as `BYTE` arrays of these lengths.

Until now I used macros to get a little endian number out of such an array. But I wanted to come up with a real C++ way of doing it, so I wrote this:

```
template <size_t Size>
struct ByteSwappedNumber
{
    BYTE bytes[Size];
    UINT64 GetValue()
    {
        UINT64 val = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(bytes); ++i)
        {
            val |= (UINT64(bytes[i]) << ((ARRAYSIZE(bytes) - i - 1) * CHAR_BIT));
        }
        return val;
    }
};
```

The question is, is it possible to change the return type of `GetValue` to the smallest possible type `>= sizeof(bytes)` using templates?

I have also looked at the Boost Endian library, but getting it to work with 24-bit numbers seems impossible. Would be happy to be shown otherwise.

Comment: Why do you need to change return type, only to suppress warnings?

Comment: To avoid conversion of all types to UINT64 when I do calculations with those numbers.

Comment: Are you avoiding that for performance purpose? Note first of all that may not be faster, second your loop solution most probably will have more significant overhead that this.

Comment: For performance and also simpler storage and transmission, because the values will be stored in other structs where there is only a USHORT or UINT for a 2- or 3-byte value. I also hoped that the compiler unrolls the loop.

Comment: I do not understand how return type of that function would affect storage. You can store `USHORT` in another struct and assign `ULONG` from this function to it (assuming you know that data will fit there). Loop may be unrolled but most probably that sitll would be slower than `__bswap_64` primitive or alike.

Comment: You're correct, but yes I want to avoid those warnings and also I guess I was trying to think economically .. not just use the biggest possible type for all values, however small. Using intrinsics might be a worthwhile optimization.

Comment: Point is if you are going to use intrinsics then just create specializations for every case and specify return type there

Answer (score 4):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve, but the mapping of some integer onto a return type can be done for example like in the following code:

```
template<size_t N> struct return_type_impl : return_type_impl<N+1>
{
    static_assert(N>=0 && N<=64, "N SHOULD BE POSITIVE AND SMALLER THAN 65");
};
template<> struct return_type_impl<64> { using type = std::int64_t; };
template<> struct return_type_impl<32> { using type = std::int32_t; };
template<> struct return_type_impl<16> { using type = std::int16_t; };
template<> struct return_type_impl<8> { using type = std::int8_t; };

template<size_t N>
using return_type = typename return_type_impl<N>::type;

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<return_type<46>, std::int64_t>::value,"");
    static_assert(std::is_same<return_type<15>, std::int16_t>::value,"");
}
```

[<kbd>Demo on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9af4d16fad57b925)

It picks the nearest available `std::intXX_t` type where `XX` is larger than the integer template argument `N`. Adjust that as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not such an expert on templates but this should do the trick:

```
using BYTE = unsigned char;

template<size_t Size>
struct type_size
{
    using type = typename std::conditional
    <
        Size <= sizeof(uint8_t),
        uint8_t,
        typename std::conditional
        <
            Size <= sizeof(uint16_t),
            uint16_t,
            typename std::conditional
            <
                Size <= sizeof(uint32_t),
                uint32_t,
                uint64_t
            >::type
        >::type
    >::type;
};

template <size_t Size>
struct ByteSwappedNumber
{
    using UINTXX = typename type_size<Size>::type;

    BYTE bytes[Size];

    UINTXX GetValue()
    {
        UINTXX val = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(bytes); ++i)
        {
            val |= (UINTXX(bytes[i]) << ((ARRAYSIZE(bytes) - i - 1) * CHAR_BIT));
        }
        return val;
    }
};
```